# excel: export csv file with japanese character

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, export, japanese

In my excel file, the Japanese character is shown correctly,
while when I export it as csv,
the character become question marks
How should I output so that the character can be shown correctly?

Comment: What OS are you on? Have you tried using unicode? [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087432/excel-xlsx-file-saving-as-csv-file-korean-and-japanese-cracking-badly)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to save the Excel spreadsheet as a Unicode Text file and then open the text file in Notepad and replace all tab characters with a comma.

1. In Excel, click the Office button in the top, left-hand corner, and then click **Save As...**
2. Choose a file name and select Unicode Text from the **Save as type** drop-down box.

   [image: Office Save Dialog to Save As Type Unicode Text]
3. Open the file you just saved in Notepad
4. Under the **Edit** menu, select **Replace...** (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
5. In the **Find what:** field, paste a Tab character.
6. In the **Replace with:** field, enter a comma.
7. Click **Replace All** and then save the text file.

   [image: Replace Tabs with commas in Notepad]

Answer (score 1):

The point is, you need to **save the file as UTF-8 and NOT as ASCII**.
Try this:

- (1) Open an Excel file where you have the info (.xls, .xlsx)
- (2) In Excel, choose "CSV (Comma Delimited) (*.csv) as the file type and save as that type.
- (3) In NOTEPAD (found under "Programs" and then Accessories in Start menu), open the saved .csv file in Notepad
- (4) Then choose -> Save As..and at the bottom of the "save as" box, there is a select box labelled as "Encoding". Select UTF-8 (do NOT use ANSI or you lose all accents etc). After selecting UTF-8, then save the file to a slightly different file name from the original.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download and install **[Unicode CSV Addin](https://github.com/jaimonmathew/Unicode-CSV-Addin)** for excel.
2. Save the csv from the new "Unicode CSV" menu as shown in picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about going to https://outlook.office.com/mail/
Click on the Contacts folder.
At the top right, click Manage Contact, Import Contact?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].